# Laravel Virgin: Access inverse model relationship in a model's mutator that participate in the relationship

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent

In my logic I have these tables:

```
Table Grid:
id PK
width INT
height INT

Table Rover:
id pk
grid_pos_x UNSIGNED INT
grid_pos_y  UNSIGNED INT
grid_id UNSINGED BIGINT
```

NOTE: I kept minimal in order to be more explanatory, for full table specs look on migration scripts below.

And I use the following migration script to create the schemas:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateGridTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('grid', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('width');
            $table->unsignedInteger('height');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('grid');
    }
}
```

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateRoverTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('rover', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->bigInteger('grid_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('command');
            $table->foreign('grid_id')->references('id')->on('grid');
            $table->smallInteger('last_commandPos')->unsigned()->default(0);
            $table->smallInteger('grid_pos_x')->unsigned();
            $table->smallInteger('grid_pos_y')->unsigned();
            $table->enum('rotation', App\Constants\RoverConstants::ORIENTATIONS);
            $table->string('last_command');

            Schema::enableForeignKeyConstraints();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('rover');
    }
}
```

And I try to model the table `rover` with the following model:

```
namespace App\Model;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Model\Grid;

class Rover extends Model
{

    /**
     * Table Name
     */
    protected $table='rover';

    public function grid()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Grid::class);
    }

    public function setGridPosXValue($value)
    {

    }

    public function setGridPosYValue($value)
    {

    }
}
```

And in a similar fashion the Grid model as well:

```
namespace App\Model;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Model\Rover;

class Grid extends Model
{
    /**
     * Table Name
     */
    protected $table='grid';

    public function rovers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Rover::class);
    }
}
```

What I want to achieve is to access the `width` and `height` attributes from the `Grid` in order to check whether the `grid_pos_x` and `grid_pos_y` are smaller from the `width` and `height` using the methods `setGridPosXValue` and the `setGridPosYValue` respectively.

Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Are you trying to go through all rovers to do this or just one at a time?

Comment: I try just this one. In case og all together I would have to iterate all of them and afterwards to do the check manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have a one to many relationship setup here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

To get the grid for a rover you can access it in multiple ways:

Directly:

```
$width = $Rover->grid->width;
$height = $Rover->grid->height;
```

With the builder methods:

```
$Grid = $Rover->grid()->first();
$width = $Grid->width;
$height = $Grid->height;
```